# Get Property Name of Part that is Selected

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am currently making a web page that uses the forge viewer. How can I make a function that will return the value from the "Properties" tab inside the viewer. I need to be able to get the value of the 'name' property inside the viewer, when a part is selected by the user. Any help is much appreciated!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, onSelectionChanged)
function onSelectionChanged(dbids){
    console.log(dbids)
    viewer.getProperties(dbIds, props => {
        props.properties.forEach(prop => {
            // any custom action with data?
            //prop.displayName 
            //prop.displayValue
            //prop.displayCategory
            // etc
        });
}
```

Blog: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/property-inspector-viewer